# Same code gives different result

Tags: java, logic

I am getting 2 different result for the same code (written almost in the same way). 
The excise was taken from: 
[codingbat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p126212)

The excise was:

"Given a string, return a version where all the "yak" are removed, but the "a" can be any char. The "yak" strings will not overlap".

The formal solution at "codingbat" was:

```
public String stringYak(String str) {
  String result = "";

  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
// Look for i starting a "yak" -- advance i in that case
if (i+2<str.length() && str.charAt(i)=='y' && str.charAt(i+2)=='k') {
  i =  i + 2;
} else { // Otherwise do the normal append
  result = result + str.charAt(i);
}
}

return result;
}
```

My solution  was:

```
public String stringYak(String str){
        int len = str.length();
        String resultNoYak = "";
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++){        
                if ((i+2<len)&&(str.charAt(i)=='y')&&(str.charAt(i+3)=='k'))    {
                i=i+2;
            }
            else {
                resultNoYak = resultNoYak + (str.charAt(i));    
            }
        }
    return resultNoYak;
}

}
```

For input: yakpak

The first code returns:
     pak (correct)

My code returns:
     yakpak (not correct)

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: It's *not* the same code, in the first it's `i + 2`, in the second it's `i + 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line

`if ((i+2<len)&&(str.charAt(i)=='y')&&(str.charAt(i+3)=='k'))`

should be

`if ((i+2<len)&&(str.charAt(i)=='y')&&(str.charAt(i+2)=='k'))`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that at all... So simple, so annoying...

Answer (score 0):

First code

```
str.charAt(i+2)=='k'
```

Your code

```
str.charAt(i+3)=='k'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code third condition is causing problem.
The line:

```
if ((i+2 < len) && (str.charAt(i) == 'y') && (str.charAt(i+3) == 'k'))
```

Should be:

```
if ((i+2 < len) && (str.charAt(i) == 'y')&&(str.charAt(i+2) == 'k'))
```

It should work fine :)